# Type non-English characters via androidviewclient

Tags: android, genymotion, androidviewclient

1. Is there a way to type non-English characters via androidviewclient? Cyrillic in my case. I added Russian layout to Genymotion and all others Input methods but no luck.
2. Or maybe a way to use Copy/Paste? This solution is even better, because I need to type some emojis also.

I'm using Genymotion with Android 4.2.2 (API 17).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current **AndroidViewClient** relies on `input` command to type characters and it crashes when non-ascii chars are sent. You can try:

```
root@hammerhead:/ # input text öüï                                             
Killed
```

It's in the roadmap to implement alternative methods to find a workaround for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I found workaround myself [ADBKeyBoard](https://github.com/senzhk/ADBKeyBoard)